# How can I incrementally calculate a time series average?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, time-series

If I have a time series s, and if you'll pardon the pseudo code, such that

```
s = {t_i, v_i}
```

is there an easy way to calculate the series

```
{t_i, Mean[s[[t_0 ;; t_i]]}
```

As I say this is pseudo code. In reality `s` is a TimeSeries object

```
s = TimeSeries[v,{t}]
```

I can generate a new TimeSeries object using MovingAverage with ease, but that is not what I require. What I do require is to create a TimeSeries object which is at time `t` the mean of values in the initial time series having a timestamp less than or equal to `t`

I could code this up for a simple sequence, but given MovingAverage is supported I was hoping for something similar for this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [MovingAverage](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingAverage.html?q=MovingAverage) ?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html)and [`TimeSeriesThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesThread.html).

With

```
s = TimeSeries[{a, b, c}];
```

then

```
t = TimeSeriesThread[Apply[Divide], {Accumulate[s], Range@s["PathLength"]}];
t["Values"]
```

> { a , (a+b)/2 , (a+b+c)/3 }

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `TimeSeriesWindow`:

```
{#, Mean@TimeSeriesWindow[ts, {tmin, #}]} & /@ tvalues
```